# deny from all in .htaccess not blocking file in the corresponding folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file in the folder called folder and another file, called form.html in the same folder
When I try to reach the folder (by entering http://blablabla/folder/), it does block the access and I am getting an error 403 but when I enter the exact URL of the file http://blablabla/folder/form.html anf hit enter, I can access the file as easily as if I haven't put any .htaccess file.

Am I doing something wrong?
Am I missing something, should I use something like  or

Sorry if the question is really basic...

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is a container for directives for your apache web server that apply to that directory and below only. What directives have you got in your .htaccess file?

The behaviour you outline above is how apache should behave with no .htaccess folder.

What is it that you are wanting to happen?

Comment: I actually intend to block all access to the files that are located in the folder called folder (I was using the form.html file to test if that .htaccess setup was actualy blocking the access).
I am doing this with my free webhosting account so I suppose that it may be other settings that are making t not work

Comment: I forgot to mention that the content of my .htaccess file is simply:
`deny from all`